# Passing values to a javascript function in a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, modal-dialog

If a user clicks the delete user button, I display a modal window asking for confirmation of the delete.  Within the modal window, if they click yes, then a function is called to delete the user (via ajax).  If no, then the modal window is just closed.  That is how it should work.  But I don't know how to pass the user ID to the yes button.  Below is what I have so far to delete the user but it may be way off.

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="DeleteUserModal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
    <h3>Delete User?</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <p>Are you sure you want to permanently remove this user?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <a href="javascript:deleteUser(#rsData.UserID#)" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, I'm sure</a>
            <button class="btn" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal">No way!</button>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="##" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
```

I do not know how to pass the userid to this specific line in the above modal window:

```
<a href="javascript:deleteUser(#rsData.UserID#)" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, I'm sure</a>
```

While I am using jQuery, the answer can be written in JavaScript.

Comment: Please post your code that listens for the button click and displays the modal window.  Your answer lies within...

Comment: I figued out this part `$('#YesDeleteuserButton').html("<a href=\"javascript:deleteUser(" + id + ",'" + cn + "')\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Yes, I'm sure</a>");` but now the modal window wont close.  :facepalm:

Comment: @Madbreaks I did not have any listeners setup which was part of the problem.  While I figured out the part to make the modal window appear (in the comments above), it is not what I ended up going with.  Chris's answer below solved both problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the data-attributes. They'll make you happy. http://www.broken-links.com/2010/11/18/data-attributes-in-html-and-jquery/

Rather give this node:

```
<a href="javascript:deleteUser(#rsData.UserID#)" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, I'm sure</a>
```

..an id:

```
<a id="delete-user-link" class="btn btn-danger">Yes, I'm sure</a>
```

..when you want to delete a specific user (thus click on the delete button in the list), set the data-attribute for the specific user-id:

```
$(".delete-button").click(function(){
    $("#delete-user-link").data("user-id", $(this).data("user-id");
    // show the modal
});
```

this does require your delete-buttons (in the list) to have a data-attribute, like:

```
<a class="btn" data-user-id="123">delete</a>
```

and add a small jQuery method:

```
$("#delete-user-link").click(function(){
    var userId = $(this).data("user-id");
    // do your delete stuff here
});
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: your code did the trick but now how do I get it to close the modal window?  This is the only way I know to manually do it is by clicking the No way! button `<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">No way!</button>`

Comment: figured out how to close it:  http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modals-tutorial.php using this code: `  $('#DeleteUserModal').modal('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

For the click to load the modal window:

```
var delete_id = 1234;// Set this to the appropriate value
$(".span12 a.btn-danger").attr("href", "javascript:deleteUser("+delete_id+")");
```